# ngOnInit not waiting for constructor service call

Tags: angular

I'm doing a API call on a constructor of a component.

```
apiResult = [];
constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private applicationServices: ApplicationService,
        private location: Location,
    ) {
        this.applicationServices.getAppConfig().subscribe(
           result => {
              this.apiResult = result;
           }
```

Then on ngOnInit i want to use that information example:

```
ngOnInit() {
  console.log('Selected App');
  console.log(this.apiResult );
}
```

However its reading the ngOnInit before the service on the constructor finish. So the result of "apiResult" is undefined.

What options do i have and whats the best way to do this? If possible can you provide an example.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The call and subscription are asynchronous by design. The constructor does not block and wait for the call to finish before exiting the constructor. This is something you must keep in mind when implementing asynchronous calls, regardless of whether they're in the constructor or not. You'd potentially have a similar problem if you subscribed in ngOnInit and then tried to leverage the results in ngAfterViewChecked or something.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The actual reason is that the dependencies (parameters of your constructor) is injected and component itself is instanced. During adding this component to the DOM, various life cycle functions execute depending on some situations.

Another thing is that your `.getAppConfig()` returns an `Observable` which is an asynchronous function. Here the function `.getAppConfig()` will execute in your `constructor` but at the same time ngOnInit() also executes. So Obviously, the `this.apiResult` will be empty at that time because assigning of values to this array is not done yet.

So, the solution could be:

```
apiResult = [];
constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private applicationServices: ApplicationService,
        private location: Location,
    ) {   }

ngOnInit(){
 this.applicationServices.getAppConfig()
       .subscribe(result => {
              this.apiResult = result;
              consoloe.log(this.apiResult);
       });
}
```

Here as all suggests, keep the constructor definition clean for best practices.

You can  read about async and normal function differences. Also, most importantly, Observables.

Comment: I was complicating stuff... 

Did what you did and added  "<div class="container" *ngIf="apiResult != null">

So it only renders when it gets a result from the API.

Answer (score 3):

While developing Angular applications, I'd suggest keeping constructors clean and just to manage dependencies.

This is what I'd recommend doing:

```js
export class Lol {
    apiResult = [];

    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private applicationServices: ApplicationService,
        private location: Location,
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.applicationServices
            .getAppConfig()
            .pipe(
                tap(result => {
                    console.log('Selected App');
                    console.log(result);
                })
            )
            .subscribe(result => {
                this.apiResult = result;
            })
    }
}
```

Call service in `ngOnInit()` and just `tap` result before subscribing to it, this is a `rxjs` operator used to do side effects and `console.log` is exactly that.

**Update**

I'd recommend against subscribing to observables manually at all, better use `async` pipe to do that. This way you'll avoid possible memory leaks and will let angular manage subscriptions for you.

That'd be component file:

```js
export class LolComponent {
  apiResult$: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private applicationServices: ApplicationService,
    private location: Location
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.apiResult$ = this.applicationServices.getAppConfig().pipe(
      tap((result) => {
        console.log("Selected App");
        console.log(result);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

That'd be the template:

```html
<div class="container" *ngIf="(apiResult$ | async) as apiResult">
    {{ apiResult | json }}
</div>
```

Comment: @Fábio I see you have very common use case for rendering, check updated example that doesn't subscribe to observable directly, but rather lets Angular handle the subscription.